# Checking Pligg CMS User Account for Login through Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, pligg

I am stuck trying to figure out a way of checking if a user is logged into one system (Pligg CMS) while on a Wordpress blog. The installation directories would look as follows:

Pligg CMS install: www.mysite.com/

Wordpress install: www.mysite.com/articles/

I'm not sure if anybody knows about how Pligg or Wordpress works with user management and login details. I'm sure I could put the pieces together, I'm just having a very difficult time getting started. How can I pull information from Pligg's login session into the WP installation which will be inside a sub-directory? Is there a PHP class I could use, or is there a better way of approaching the problem which I'm not aware of?

If there's anything confusing or strangely worded please let me know. I'll be happy to clarify any problems as I'd really love to solve this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try taking a look at these two links, they might be of use:

http://thedeadone.net/how-to/integrating-pligg-beta-810-with-wordpress-204/
http://forums.pligg.com/questions-comments/2180-pligg-using-wordpress-authentication.html

Comment: Thanks I actually found a very [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218804/help-single-sign-on-between-wordpress-and-pligg) right here on StackOverflow.. so I think this should work out well.